# How to leave out duplicate results in this join query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a join query returning these results:

My taught lessons:

```
2017-04-02 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00 
2017-04-02 : 15:00:00 - 16:30:00
2017-04-02 : 17:00:00 - 18:00:00
2017-04-02 : 18:10:00 - 19:10:00
2017-04-03 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00
2017-04-04 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00
2017-04-05 : 17:45:00 - 18:45:00
2017-04-08 : 08:50:00 - 10:20:00
2017-04-08 : 10:30:00 - 12:00:00
2017-04-08 : 17:30:00 - 18:30:00
...
```

Is it possible to show every date only once using sql on MySQL server 5.7? Or should this be done later using php? The results are like this because it's possible to teach multiple lessons on one day, but one lesson belongs to one day only.

Like this: My taught lessons:

```
2017-04-02 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00 
             15:00:00 - 16:30:00
             17:00:00 - 18:00:00
             18:10:00 - 19:10:00
2017-04-03 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00
2017-04-04 : 10:00:00 - 12:00:00
2017-04-05 : 17:45:00 - 18:45:00
2017-04-08 : 08:50:00 - 10:20:00
             10:30:00 - 12:00:00
             17:30:00 - 18:30:00
...
```

here's the query. I tried doing a subquery for the date join, but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT
  lessons_date,
  start_times,
  end_times
FROM lessons
JOIN lesson_date
  ON id_lessons_date = lesson_date_id_lessons_date
JOIN start_time
  ON id_start_times = start_time_has_end_time_start_time_id_start_times
JOIN end_time
  ON id_end_times = start_time_has_end_time_end_time_id_end_times;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  And tag your questions with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database not used to display data, As you want to present them in a web page so you have to find a way to fetch them from the database then depending on fetching way you can present them.

```
SELECT
  lessons_date,
  group_concat(start_times SEPARATOR ',') start_times,
  group_concat(end_times SEPARATOR ',') end_times
FROM lessons
JOIN lesson_date
  ON id_lessons_date = lesson_date_id_lessons_date
JOIN start_time
  ON id_start_times = start_time_has_end_time_start_time_id_start_times
JOIN end_time
  ON id_end_times = start_time_has_end_time_end_time_id_end_times;
GROUP BY lessons_date
```

Then in your `PHP` add something like:

```
$start_times = explode(",", $row["start_times"]); // array of times
for ($time as $start_times) {
    echo $time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for and there's probably a more elegant way to do this, but here's an idea for you:

```
    SELECT
    CreatedOn = 
        CASE 
        WHEN name is null 
        THEN CreatedOn
        ELSE null
        END
    , Name
    FROM (
        select distinct 
            createdon
            ,null as name
            ,createdon as c2
        FROM account
        UNION
        SELECT 
            a.createdon
            ,a.name
            ,a.createdon as c2
            FROM account a
            JOIN account b on a.createdon = b.createdon
        ) x
    ORDER BY c2, name
```

Returns this:

[image: SQL results]

You might want to consider formatting it in PHP...

Comment: I would rather do it on the server or client side as it is related to data presentation rather than extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it . This will give exact result.

```
 SELECT 
   temp.lessons_date , 
   GROUP_CONCAT(start_times SEPARATOR '<br/>') , 
   GROUP_CONCAT(end_times SEPARATOR '<br/>') FROM (
      SELECT
      lessons_date,
      start_times,
      end_times
    FROM lessons
    JOIN lesson_date
      ON id_lessons_date = lesson_date_id_lessons_date
    JOIN start_time
      ON id_start_times = start_time_has_end_time_start_time_id_start_times
    JOIN end_time
      ON id_end_times = start_time_has_end_time_end_time_id_end_times ORDER BY temp.lessons_date 


   ) temp GROUP BY temp.lessons_date
```